# In Javascript, if there is an object with a lot of properties that are functions, how do you convert them to array of strings (of the function names)?

Tags: javascript, stringification

In Javascript, if an object has lots of properties that are functions:

```
var obj = { foo: function() { ... },
            bar: function() { ... },
              ...
          }
```

then how can you get an array of names of those functions?  That is, an array

```
["foo", "bar", ... ]
```

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var names = [];
for( var k in obj ) {
   if(obj.hasOwnProperty(k) && typeof obj[k] == 'function') {
      names.push(k);
   }
}
```

Comment: interesting, how come push will not push a function reference into the array but will push the name of the function?

Comment: `for in` loops over property names, not the actual properties. So if you want to reference each property, you would use `obj[k]`.

Comment: so what if there is only 1 function inside, still have to use a "for in" loop to achieve this purpose?  is there another way if "for in" loop doesn't exist?

Comment: to enumerate properties you have to use `for..in`. There is no other *correct* way.

Answer (score 3):

```
var functions = [];
for (var prop in obj) {
    if ((typeof obj[prop]) == 'function') {
        // it's a function
        functions.push(prop);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** I've slightly misread the question, you want to extract the names of *only* the properties that are function objects:

```
function methods(obj) {
  var result = [];
  for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof obj[prop] == 'function') {
      result.push(prop);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var obj = {
  foo: function() { },
  bar: function() { },
};

methods(obj); // ["foo", "bar"]
```

I'm using the [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method, to ensure that the enumerated properties in fact exist physically in the object.

Note that this approach and all other answers have a small problem IE.

The [JScript's DontEnum Bug](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/ECMAScript_DontEnum_attribute#JScript_DontEnum_Bug), custom properties that shadow non-enumerable properties (`DontEnum`) higher in the prototype chain, are not enumerated using the for-in statement, for example :

```
var foo = {
  constructor : function() { return 0; },
  toString : function() { return "1"; },
  valueOf : function() { return 2; }
  toLocaleString : function() { return "3"; }
};

for (var propName in foo ) { alert(propName); }
```

The object `foo` clearly has defined four own properties, but those properties exist in `Object.prototype` marked as `DontEnum`, if you try to enumerate the properties of that object with the `for-in` statement in IE, it won't find any.

This bug is present on all IE versions, and has been recently fixed in IE9 Platform Preview.

Comment: +1 for mentioning hasOwnProperty, but I believe Jian was after just the functions, not all the properties.

Answer (score 1):

To complete other answers: you can also use `instanceof`:

```
var obj = { foo: function() { ... },
            bar: function() { ... },
              ...
          },
    fnArr = [];

for (var label in obj){
  if (obj[label] instanceof Function){
     fnArr.push(label)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With [ES5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#ECMAScript.2C_5th_Edition):

```
var obj = {
    foo: function() {},
    bar: function() {},
    baz: true
};

function getMethods(object) {
    return Object.keys(object).filter(function(key) {
        return typeof object[key] == 'function';
    });
}

getMethods(obj); // [foo, bar]
```

`Object.keys(<object>)` returns the names of all enumerable properties of an object as an array, of which the non-functions are filtered out.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vGVEs/) - works on Chrome release and nightly builds of [Webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29170) and [Tracemonkey (Firefox)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=307791).